# Optimize big integer substraction in C++

Tags: c++, c, assembly, optimization

I wrote a small library of big integer arithmetics. There is a following loop in my substraction algorithm:

```
unsigned * a, * ae, * b, * be; // pointers to array of big ints
unsigned long long C_MAX_DIG_1 = 1Ui64 << 32;
......
long long carry = 0;
for (;a != ae && b != be; ++a, ++b) {
    long long r = carry + *a - *b;
    r < 0 ? (r += C_MAX_DIG_1, carry = -1) : (carry = 0);
    *a = (unsigned)r;
}
```

This loop works properly, but I found that it's not as effective as possible. Help me with optimizing this loop (maybe, using special tricks or assembler inserts).

Comment: How do you know it's not as effective as possible?

Comment: You claim it works properly, but the variables used are uninitialised. Anyway, should the question be on CodeReview, as (apparently) working code you wish to improve?

Comment: In `a != ae` the variables are of different types. The first is a pointer, the second is `unsigned`. I do not believe the code works.

Comment: Assembly code generated is too big, and i'm sure that it can be smaller. For example, comparison may be replaced with overflow check or number of writing in memory operations may be reduced. But I don't the exact way to do it.

Comment: After the edit, it is evident you are posting **guessed code** which *resembles* your code. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could look at how GMP does it for inspiration

Comment: I just wanted to show the loop. Variable are initialized, of course, and I made a mistake writing the definition of these variables. But it doesn't matter here.

Comment: It matters a lot. Variables are only initialised when you *show* that.

Comment: It does matter. With questions like this, we want to compile the code for ourselves, read the generated assembly, and then tinker with it and see what changes will actually improve things.  Please provide a _complete function_.

Comment: (Also, I hate to be that guy, but _exactly_ which CPU are you compiling for, and what language are you actually using, C++ or C?  This affects what options you have for manual optimization.  And what is this "1Ui64"? The standard way to write a constant of type `unsigned long long` is `1ull`.)

Comment: [Anyway](https://godbolt.org/g/C2O66A), as you can see the overflow check is already optimized, and there is only one write to memory per limb. Clang makes noticeably nicer output when the double exit is made a single exit test, you could probably rewrite it that way.

Comment: Big assembly code doesn't mean that the code is not optimal.  Maybe the compiler, for example, performed loop unrolling.

Comment: By the way, hadn't you forget the proper optimization flags?  You may want -O3 for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for (;a != ae && b != be; ++a, ++b)
```

try

```
ptrdiff_t da = ae - a, db = be - b;
unsigned* ae2 = a + (da < db ? da : db);
for (;a != ae2; ++a, ++b)
```

This way, you'll save one comparison.  If the loop is long, maybe it will make things a bit faster.

Also, find the best compilation flags. Maybe you may benefit from flags matching your specific CPU (i.e. -msse3 for GCC).

Also, you may want to implement parallelism, if you have, and ready to use, more than one processor.

I doubt you can do miracles, because most of the time is spent on reading values from RAM  and writing them back (assuming they are in RAM rather than in cache memory).  RAM is slower than CPU.

Answer (score 1):

This should work and be a bit faster. I'm assuming that the first word of a big integer is the least significant word, based on the question's code.

```
// assumes size of a >= size of b
void subvv(unsigned *a, unsigned *ae, unsigned *b, unsigned *be)
{
unsigned r;                     // result
unsigned c = 0;                 // borrow
    while(b != be){
        r = *a - *b - c;
        // assuming compiler uses register for *a
        c = (r > *a)? 1 : 0;
        *a = r;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    while(c && a != ae){
        r = *a - c;
        c = (r > *a)? 1 : 0;
        *a = r;
        a++;
    }
}
```

If you're considering assembly, then most processors have a subtract with borrow instruction, eliminating the need to manually check for borrow.

Comment: `c = (r > *a)? 1 : 0` ==> `c = (r > *a)` is enough

Comment: in C logical operators always return 0 and 1